# how can I create overlay div to fit the rest of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can create overlay div with black background lets say, I have an anchor that fires div to popup, here is the anchor:

```
<a href="#" title="Open online form" id="open">Suggest</a>
```

Here is the css of centered div :

```
.centered
{
  width:55%;
  position:fixed;
  left:18%;
  height:200px;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:none;
}

 $("#open").live('click', function(){
            var divTop = 75 + $(window).scrollTop();    // places the popup 75px from the top       
         $('.centered').css({'top':divTop, 'display':'block', 'z-index':'5005'});
            });
```

I used jquery ui modal for these things before, but now some of my scripts stop working when I use it, and plus 50kb+ is something I don't need on my website at the moment, already loading for app 6 sec. Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you wish to continue using jQuery UI you can use just the necessary files, like ui.core.js, which I'm pretty sure won't get you up to 50+ KB.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if your site is already at a 6 second load time, you've got much bigger problems w/ your setup than jquery.  Have a look at the YSlow test (google it) to figure out where you can improve. I'm guessing gzip & combining images would help to begin with.  Another hting to look at is the mode you're site's in; for example, a .NET MVC site under 'debug' mode functions orders of magnitude slower than one in production mode (debug='false', compilation=release)

Comment: @Paul thank you paul I'll google that .. what do you mean by "gzip"?

Comment: When your server transfers to the client, the content is usually zipped then unzipped on their end, so the actual transfer across the pipe is much smaller.  Look here for a good rundown: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: gzip is done by the server to compress the output before sending to the user. YSlow has more information regarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [**blockUI** for this?](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) 8k **before GZip**, this is all it does, shouldn't give you any trouble with other scripts.  The main benefit for me is it takes care of things like IE6 dropdowns bleeding through, all the little annoyances, etc.

Your case would be:

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('.centered') }); //show
$.unblockUI(); //hide
```